# solidity error with addr.transfer(1 ether)

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Error message:

> transact to Payment.deposit errored: VM error: revert.
>   revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
>   Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.  Debug the transaction to get more information.

```
contract Payment{ 
address Account2;
address Owner;

constructor() public{
    Account2 = 0x583031D1113aD414F02576BD6afaBfb302140225;
    Owner = msg.sender;
}
function deposit() payable public{
    address(uint160(Account2)).transfer(1 ether);
}
```

Comment: i dont want to fill in msg.value to conclude transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use msg.value then it is compulsory that your contract should have enough balance.
So you can create a fallback function in order to deposit enough ether to your contract first and then you can call your **deposit()** function.

Your contract after adding fallback function

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
contract Payment{ 
    address Account2;
    address Owner;

    constructor() public{
        Account2 = 0x583031D1113aD414F02576BD6afaBfb302140225;
        Owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function () payable external{}
    function deposit() payable public{
        address(uint160(Account2)).transfer(1 ether);
    }

    function getContractBalance() public view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: remix starts with 100ether per account, which is suffice to deliver

Comment: That's probably because you are using Javasctript VM environment.
And moreover that's the balance of user account and not of contract's.
So you have to send some amount of 100ether to contract by placing value and calling fallback function.

Comment: I have updated my answer and added a function to check contract balance which returns value in wei(1ether = 10^18 Wei). 
So your deposit function will only work if balance is greater than or equal to 1 ether

Comment: i got it now, account balance != contract balance. And one more question, under the same circumstance, why msg.value can be success?

Comment: msg.value is used to send ether to contract from user's account, so while you are using msg.value balnce is deducted from your 100ethers(user account) and sent to contract address and there after it is transferred to defined Account2 address

Comment: @DushyanthKumarReddy msg.value is not used to send ether, it’s used to check how many ether has it received. Also it could be the amount of ether sent from a contract, not necessary to be an user’s account.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I've said that as per his scenario, since he is calling it from account.And for msg.value,  in the context of remix we has to place some amount of ether or wei in Value tab to send it to contract

Answer (score 1):

It works without error on my remix VM.

So make sure:

1. The contract has a balance greater than 1 ether
2. If `Account2` is a contract's address, then it need to have a fallback function to receive ether